# convert text into binary matrix in R

Tags: r, csv, matrix

I have following text, contents are as follows

```
#------------------
# CONTENTS OF TEXT
#------------------

H01, H04, G02, G06, 
H01, H02, G02, H05, 
G01, H04, H01
G09, G05
```

I want to convert this data in to binary matrix. I want the output to be like this

```
H01 H02 H04 H05 G01 G02 G05 G06 G09
1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0
1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1
```

Please help

Comment: can you please `dput` your data: `dput(data)` in this case? Also, you should not be able to run `read.csv(file)` without some kind of warning or error.

Comment: I have made the changes in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
d <- read.table(header=FALSE, sep='§', stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text=
'H01, H04, G02, G06, 
H01, H02, G02, H05, 
G01, H04, H01
G09, G05')
s <- sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(d$V1, ', *'))))
m <- sapply(s, grepl, x=d$V1, fixed=TRUE)
# > m
#        G01   G02   G05   G06   G09   H01   H02   H04   H05
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
m[] <- as.integer(m)
# > m
#      G01 G02 G05 G06 G09 H01 H02 H04 H05
# [1,]   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
# [2,]   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1
# [3,]   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
# [4,]   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea using @jogo data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d %>%
  mutate(V1 = stringi::stri_extract_all_words(V1), V2 = 1) %>%
  unnest(V1, .id = "id") %>%
  spread(V1, V2, fill = 0)
```

Which gives:

```
#  id G01 G02 G05 G06 G09 H01 H02 H04 H05
#1  1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
#2  2   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1
#3  3   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
#4  4   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
```